# Vertical path to node in TikZ trees

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, trees

How can I set the path between two specific nodes to "vertical" rather than "direct"?

Currently my tree looks like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=1.5cm,
    every node/.style={draw=black,very thick,minimum width=10mm,inner sep=2mm},
    every path/.style={thick},
    level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
    level 2/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
    level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.5cm,level distance=10mm},
    leaf/.style={fill=black,minimum width=2mm,minimum height=2mm,inner sep=0mm}]
    \node{10}
        child{node{8}
            child{node{5}
                child{node[leaf]{}}
                child{node[leaf]{}}
            }
            child{node{9}
                child{node[leaf]{}}
                child{node[leaf]{}}
            }
        }
        child{node{20}
            child{node{12}
                child{node[leaf]{}}
                child{node[leaf]{}}
            }
            child{node{21 29}
                child[edge from parent]{node[leaf]{}}
                child{node[leaf]{}}
                child{node[leaf]{}}
            }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: B-Tree]

I would like to have the paths between the last row and the leafs to be vertical, rather than diagonal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the way edges are drawn with the `edge from parent path` key.  Change the `level 3/.style` line to:

```
level 3/.style={
    sibling distance=0.5cm,
    level distance=10mm,
    edge from parent path={
        (\tikzchildnode.north) -- (\tikzchildnode.north |- \tikzparentnode.south)
    }
},
```

If `A` and `B` are coordinates, then `A |- B` is the intersection of a vertical line through `A` and a horizontal line through `B`.  So `(A) -- (A |- B)` draws a line to this intersection.

[image: sample code output]

If you're going to do this a lot, make your own style:

```
\tikzset{edge from parent vertical/.style={
   edge from parent path={
       (\tikzchildnode.north) -- (\tikzchildnode.north |- \tikzparentnode.south)
   }
}}
```

then you can change the line to:

```
level 3/.style={sibling distance=0.5cm,level distance=10mm,edge from parent vertical}
```

Comment: The `|-` syntax is a solution to many problems. Thank for pointing at it.